# WooCommerce quick checkout form?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, order

I have a site powered by WordPress and using WooCommerce Plugin. I want to add a custom quick checkout form on a single product page.

For reference, see the image Quick checkout form:

[image]

Can I make a custom form and place order? Any Solution???